# Document is not deleted if delete request was sent immediately after insert request

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a service that indexes documents.
The service receives two following requests - the first is to insert a document and the second to delete it.
When there is some time between them it works fine but when they are sent one after another the document is not deleted.
The response from I get from Nest looks successful.

My function is kinds long so I will only write the insert and delete inside. If more info is needed I will add it (For example, in case of insertion in also deletes it from all other available indices and inserts some mapping if needed).

Insert code:

```
IBulkResponse res = await _client.IndexManyAsync(entities, index, type);
```

Delete Code:

```
var termFilter = new List<Func<QueryContainerDescriptor<JObject>, QueryContainer>>
        {
            c => c.Terms(t => t.Field(ID_FIELD).Terms(ids))
        };

        await _client.DeleteByQueryAsync<JObject>(indices, types, d => d.Query(q => q.Bool(b => b.Must(termFilter))));
```

For example, this integration test doesn't work:

```
var indices = new { "some_index_1", "some_index_2" };
var entity = new Entity {  Action = ReplicationAction.INSERT, ... };
await elasticDal.Insert(new List { entity }, "some_index_1", "666", indices);
entity.Action = ReplicationAction.DELETE;
await elasticDal.Insert(new List { entity }, "some_index_1", "666", indices);
```

Versions: ElasticSearch 2.3.5, .Net 4.6, Nest 2.4.6

Comment: This question doesn't have a accepted answer. How did you fixed that problem?

Comment: If I remember correctly I didn't solve it using Elasticsearch. Instead, I held back the incoming requests for a short time in a cache and if a new request arrived with the same id I removed the previous entities still in the cache

Answer (score 0):

When you are inserting any document following steps happens:

1. Document is added to the in-memory buffer and appended to the translog.
2. Refresh
   The docs in the in-memory buffer are written to a new segment, without
   a Fsync.

   ```
   a. The segment is opened to make it visible to search.

   b. The in-memory buffer is cleared.
   ```
3. The segment is opened to make it visible to search.
4. Every so often—such as when the translog is getting too big—the index is
   flushed; a new translog is created, and a full commit is performed :

   a. Any docs in the in-memory buffer are written to a new segment.

   b. The buffer is cleared.

   c. A commit point is written to disk.

   d. The filesystem cache is flushed with a Fsync.

   e. The old translog is deleted.

Elasticsearch doesn't delete the document. It marks the document as a deleted document, and while merging the index segments, ES leaves deleted document if it is in memory.

So my guess is you are missing refresh API after deleting.
**If your DELETE API is not so frequent, then you can refresh your ES after calling DELETE API by calling REFRESH API.**

If you want to learn more about how indexing is happing behind the picture, you can refer to this link (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/translog.html)

Comment: the deletes are quite frequent in this case. and there are other cases when i need to delete many docs at once. should i still use the refresh api? if not, what else can i do?

Comment: i just tried using the refresh api ( await _client.RefreshAsync(new RefreshRequest(indices)) ) but it doest help

Comment: ES do refresh every second. So can put a sleep for let say one you two second and if your frequency is less than one document per second you can put refresh.
But my suggestion is put sleep of one second.

Comment: What was the final solution for this issue?